# how to get hours worked

Tags: vba

I want to calculate hours worked when the finish time falls in a different date.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub calcHours()
    Dim start, finish As Date
    start = DateValue("2021/03/28") & " " & TimeValue("18:30:00")
    finish = DateValue("2021/03/29") & " " & TimeValue("02:30:00")
    
    Debug.Print hoursWorked(start, finish)
End Sub

Private Function hoursWorked(ByVal start As Date, ByVal finish As Date) As Date
    Dim startDateAndTime, finishDateAndTime As Date
    startDateAndTime = start
    finishDateAndTime = finish
    
    'this will obviously not work.
    hoursWorked = finishDateAndTime - startDateAndTime
End Function
```

Comment: This displays `8:00:00`, which looks correct to me.

Comment: @GSerg, sorry i tried it on finish date as 2021/03/30

Comment: [`DateDiff("h", start, finish)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function)?